# Consistency of maximum likelihood for not-identically distributed observations

Tags: maximum-likelihood, consistency

Let $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers and let
$$
 A=\left\{f:\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+:\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k,\mu)=1,\;\sum_{k=0}^\infty k f(k,\mu)=\mu\;\forall\mu\in\mathbb{R}_+\right\}.
$$
Let $f_\star\in A$ and set $\mathbb{P}=\bigotimes_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}_i$, where each $\mathbb{P}_i$ has probability mass function $f_\star(\cdot,\mu_i)$.

Is it true that then
$$
\mathrm{argmax}_{f\in A}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\ell=1}^n\log\big(f(X_\ell,\mu_\ell)\big)\to f_\star
$$
in $\mathbb{P}$-probability?